# Code sign bundled app made with osacompile

Tags: bash, firefox, applescript

Programmatically I trying to achieve this on Mac OS X: a file on desktop that when clicked will launch Firefox with a certain profile.

I do this with AppleScript and bash.

#### Manual steps

1. Open the Script Editor
2. Write some AppleScript (`do shell script "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -ProfileManager &> /dev/null &"`)
3. Save your new AppleScript > Save As > Application Bundle
4. Set icon

This works perfectly fine manually it follows this tutorial: [Asa Dotzler Blog Firefox Shortcut](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/asa/archives/2008/08/shortcut_to_lau.html)

However programmatically I'm having some problems.

I successfully make the file and put it on desktop with `/bin/bash/osacompile -`.

#### Programmatic Steps

1. Programmatic Step 1 - create a script.txt file with the code on desktop

   ```
   var path_src = OS.Path.join(
       OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir,
       'script.txt'
   );
   var path_exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []).path;
   var write_file = OS.File.writeAtomic(
       path_src,
       'do shell script "' + path_exe + ' -P -no-remote &> /dev/null &"'
   );
   ```
2. Compile the .txt to .app and put it on desktop code:

   ```
   var path_compile = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir,'script.app');
   var osacompile = File.initWithPath("/usr/bin/osacompile");
   if (MacVersion <= 10.6) {
       osacompile.arguments = ["-o", path_compile, path_src]
   } else {
       //for >= 10.7
       osacompile.arguments = [
           "-t",
           "osas",
           "-c",
           "ToyS",
           "-o",
           path_compile,
           path_src
       ]
   }
   osacompile.run();
   ```

But when user clicks it they get this error:

> ""script" can't be opened because it is from an unidentified developer."

Image:

[image]

I heard maybe this can be code signed? How can I code sign it so I can bypass this error and start working on setting icon?

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search for "applescript code sign" turns up lots of info.

Another option: if the code is to run on your computer you can just turn off the system preference that causes this. Go to Security & Privacy->General and choose the checkbox "allow apps downloaded from anywhere". Of course realize that this will do exactly what it says so it's a possible security issue. I run my computer this way but you may feel differently.

So either method will solve your issue. Good luck.

Comment: Well this is going into code for my users. I can't tell all my users to make this change. I did the google search and they are saying to remove the `com.apple.quarrantine` which doesn't help i tried but can't figure out. I don't even know if that's my issue. Also is my arguments correct for 10.4 10.5 10.6? Or did I mix up those arguments. Thanks man so much for your replies.

Comment: Any alternative to get the script to run with code signed? Im making a free addon for firefox so dont have funding to buy into the developer program.

Comment: There's free ways to code sign an app. Read through some of the google search results.