# Changing App Icon

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to make an application that generates and app (with Applescript), and so far I've gone as far as generating the normally functioning app by using the (do shell script "osacompile...") command. Now, all I need is a string that will automatically also change the icon of the generated application, as I would like my own icon to be the newly generated application's icon rather than the default Applet icon.

What are some ways to approach this?

Thanks a ton.

Eric

Comment: can you share your code plz

Comment: I won't give the exact code, but it goes along the lines of this:

set ScriptToCompile to "display dialog \"Hello, world.\""

do shell script "osacompile -x -o ~/Desktop/AppName.app -e " & quoted form of ScriptToCompile

Comment: Is that for mac os x>= 10.7, how about supporting <= 10.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using privealaged javascript from firefox this creates the app with custom icon, the only problem is, whenever you click on the app it throws "unidentified author" and doesnt run.

but this at least shows you how to set a custom icon. credit to @djBazzieWazzie for explaining above plus directories.

```
  _createShortcutMac : function(target, name, id, icon, location) {
      var desktop = dirSvc.get("Desk", Ci.nsIFile);
      this._createBundle(target, name, id, icon, desktop);
  }

  _createBundle : function(target, name, id, icon, location) {
    var contents =
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
    "<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n" +
    "<plist version=\"1.0\">\n" +
    "<dict>\n" +
    "<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>\n" +
    "<string>" + name + "</string>\n" +
    "<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>\n" +
    "<string>" + icon.leafName + "</string>\n" +
    "</dict>\n" +
    "</plist>";

    location.append(name + ".app");
    if (location.exists())
      location.remove(true);
    location.create(Ci.nsIFile.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0755);

    location.append("Contents");
    location.create(Ci.nsIFile.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0755);

    var info = location.clone();
    info.append("Info.plist");
    var stream = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
    stream.init(info, PR_WRONLY | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_TRUNCATE, 0600, 0);
    stream.write(contents, contents.length);
    stream.close();

    var resources = location.clone();
    resources.append("Resources");
    resources.create(Ci.nsIFile.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0755);
    icon.copyTo(resources, icon.leafName);

    var macos = location.clone();
    macos.append("MacOS");
    macos.create(Ci.nsIFile.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0755);

    var cmd = "#!/bin/sh\nexec " + target.path + " -webapp ID";
    var script = macos.clone();
    script.append(name);
    stream.init(script, PR_WRONLY | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_TRUNCATE, 0755, 0);
    stream.write(cmd, cmd.length);
    stream.close();
  }
```

Comment: To get rid of the "unidentified author" error you have to use `xattr` on it after creation and it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've created an app bundle, e.g. via:

```
osascript -o Foo.app foo.applescript
```

Then you can either simply overwrite the existing icon file:

```
cp -f myicon.icns Foo.app/Contents/Resources/applet.icns
```

or copy over a new icon file, and update the Info.plist:

```
rm Foo.app/Contents/Resources/applet.icns
cp myicon.icns Foo.app/Contents/Resources/
plutil -replace CFBundleIconFile -string myicon.icns Foo.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

Icons of applications are shown based on the info.plist inside the application bundle. There is a key named `CFBundleIconFile` whose value is the name of the icon file in the resource folder. The simplest way is that an AppleScript saved as application has the icon file applet.icns and replace it afterwards. Or you can add your own icon file to the resource folder, remove the icns file created by osacompile and change the info.plist file inside the bundle. Because you have no example code, which is normally required on StackOverflow, I can't help you further than this.

Comment: I like this way much more, I was struggling with this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25820369/1828637 (at bottom he links to `SetFileIcon`) can you please show us how to change icon with the code i gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859379/code-sign-bundled-app-made-with-osacompile (does the .app behave like a directory? can i iterate through files within like normal?)

Comment: Yes, you can right click on an app and show package contents to look inside the application. In UNIX, the underlying system were you execute osacompile, an app is just regular directory not a package as in Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks man I put togather some code to show this guy. Ill post as solutin.

Comment: Hey man question: I created app from command line, and then after it was made i deleted the applet.icns in the resources directory and replaced it with another icon i named applet.icns, but the icon didn't take. if i duplicate the app it takes. how can i force refresh on that app icon programtically after i changed it in the folder?

Comment: Depending on the system the icon doesn't have to change immediately in the Finder. When you view the app using quicklook you'll see the new icon. It's the Finder who needs to refresh so simply restart it (hold down alt button when clicking and holding down mouse on the Finder icon in Dock and choose restart Finder from the contextual menu).

Comment: Oh actually the icon is on my desktop, anyway to referesh the desktop via applescript? Or just refresh that .app icon?

Comment: Yeah, how do you refresh the icon?